# Adding an Observer to an API Call

Tags: android, firebase

Is there a way to add an observer to an API call which will trigger when there is a change in the data in the API, just like how Firebase observer works?
I am trying this for android.

Comment: Dit you mean you want to get notification when the data changes?

Comment: yes, i want to get notification.

Comment: You have to call API to check that. That's how Firebase does!

Comment: Does that mean i have to call the API asynchronously again and again? But wont that create an overhead ?

Comment: "again and again?" Yes. But you have to do it in foreground service